# Create grails <g:link>

Tags: grails

I have a problem using `<g:link>` tag.

When I use

```
<g:link namespace="print" controller="home" action="terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</g:link>
```

It creates the following link

```
<a href="/app/print/home/terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
```

But I would like to create a link such as

```
<a href="/app/print/home/terms#testValue">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
```

How can this be achieved?

I tried using **"${createLink(controller: 'home', action: 'terms')}** but it does not support namespace attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref: [grails-doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html)

You may use fragment (often called anchor tag).

`<g:link namespace="print" controller="home" action="terms" fragment="testValue">Terms &amp; Conditions</g:link>`